# Through the point $M(1,3)$, draw a straight line so that it cuts off in the first quadrant a rectangular triangle having a smaller hypotenuse.

Tags: derivatives

Given the task:
Through the point $M(1,3)$, draw a straight line so that it cuts off in the first quadrant a rectangular triangle having a smaller hypotenuse.

I reasoned so:
Equation of a line is expressed as
$A(x-1)+B(y-3)=0$, $A \ne 0$ and $B \ne 0$, this a hypotenuse.

And, this hypotenuse $\cap Oy = I(0; y^{*})$ and $\cap Ox = J(x^{*}; 0)$. I don't know $x^{*}$ and $y^{*}$, but I know that I need to find a $\min{x^2+y^2}$.

How do I do this using differential calculus?

Comment: hypothesis? or hypotenuse?

Comment: @AndreaMori thanks a lot

Comment: Sure. Anyway, you're on the right track: (1) write the line as $y-3=m(x-1)$; (2) compute $x^*$ and $y^*$ in terms of $m$; (3) use Calculus to find the value of $m$ that makes $(x^*)^2+(y^*)^2$ minimal.

Comment: @AndreaMori $y−3=m(x−1)$ is form: $y=kx + b$ ?